# Get start date by week and year

Tags: php, php-5.3, php-5.5, php-5.4

I have a question. I want to get the first datetime by week number and year. It's possibile ?
I try :

```
date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("$weak_number week")).
```

The idea is to get the datetime of monday for this week. Thx in advance, and sorry for my english

Answer (score 1):

```
    $date1 = date(
    'Y-m-d', 
    strtotime($year . 'W' . str_pad($week, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT))
);
```